# Searching in osx for "anything but.."

Tags: macos, spotlight

I was trying to clean up my music folders and I want to remove everything except MP3 files.

I want to know how to search for everything but MP3s and obviously the subfolders themselves.

What do I have to type into the searchlight box to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

Enter anything into the Finder's search field, and clear it again. You'll then be in the search interface that has a new bar near the top, with no active search criteria:

[image: Screenshot]

Click the `+` button at the right side of the new search context bar.

Hold <kbd>Option</kbd> and click the `…` button to the right of the new entry (it's another `+` button while you don't hold <kbd>Option</kbd>).

*Now it should look like this:*

[image: Screenshot]

Remove the first additional row (the one that showed the `…` button) by clicking its `–` button.

Then, configure the two recently added rows to say:

- `None` of the following are true

  - `Kind` is `Music` `MP3`

*Here, I'll still need to change `All` to  `MP3`, but otherwise, I'm done:*

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I didnt know the trick with the option-click ;)
But it also shows me the folders - any way to exclude them as well?
or another possibility would be to have a bar on top to sort the results by type or date or name, etc...

Comment: @stoobz: Just add another line to the `None` block that excludes the `Kind` `Folder`…

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to delete non-mp3 files anywhere under a specific directory (which I assume is the current directory), and that they are all called names ending in `.mp3`, the following should work.

```
find . -type f \! -name \*.mp3 -exec rm {} \;
```

A simpler way, pointed out in a comment below (thanks, @DanielBeck!), would be to use the `-delete` option instead.

```
find . -type f \! -name \*.mp3 -delete
```

This finds all ordinary files (`-type f`) whose name does not (`\!`) match the pattern `*.mp3`, then deletes them (`-exec rm {} \;`, or the rather simpler `-delete` option).

Comment: thank you! I will try that.
and to define the folder I have to replace the first "." with the folderpath, right?

Comment: `-delete` is a better alternative to `-exec rm`.

Comment: @stoobz - yes, the first arguments to `find` are the path to search (and you can give any number of directories).

Comment: @Daniel - thanks, shows my knowledge isn't as current as yours, probably. How often we learn one way to do a task then stick with that, even in the presence of better ways.